# How to write a sql query to multiply two values which are not present in any table?

Tags: sql

This is an interview question asked at Amazon. Help me guys!!!

Comment: `select 3 * 5 as result`?

Comment: Although the question is not well formatted because your just trying to get an interview question answered. The question itself isn't bad.

Answer (score 0):

You can save the values as a variable and then use it.

```
DECLARE @X AS INT
DECLARE @Y AS INT 
SET @X = 3
SET @Y = 4
SELECT @X * @Y
```